# JetEntityFrameworkProvider - database first

Tags: jet-ef-provider

I've been unable to get the JetEntityFrameworkProvider to work.  Couple questions/comments (running VS2017, 6.4.1 nuGet for JetEntityFrameworkProvider) wanting to connect to a MS2016 access database.

- I watched the video but when I looked at the files in the latest zip, the Key.snk file wasn't there.  I added my own but not sure if anything else needs to change?
- For the JetDdexProvider, added a new resource name of GenerateAssemblyInfo and set the value to false so I could set the version the same as a one from the nuGet package I pulled (6.1.4) otherwise when building VS adds 2 lines to the AssemblyInfo.cs and then complains that they already exist:

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("6.1.4.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("6.1.4.0")]

- The pre-build command wasn't finding the vsvars32.bat so I changed it to:
  call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"
  gacutil /u JetEntityFrameworkProvider.dll
- I'm running VS2017.  I updated the install.config to have: SET REGROOT=SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config.  I see key HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3512878864-1034292029-1113751564-1001\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0_Config\DataProviders{52C271ED-FAE1-444E-8C3A-6DFEC4C3A974} in the registry but the PlatformVersion is 2.  This should be 6.4.1 (?)

When I try to create my edmx file for database first, I only have the SQL server dataproviders listed so trying to track down where I went wrong.

Thanks
SleepyBadger

Comment: Sorry, for the last bullet, should be 6.1.4, not 6.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be the DDEX registration (the one you are trying to do on the registry) or version of the provider.
About DDEX probably the simplest way is to set the registry key in current user so you are sure you are choosing the right user.
VS2017 is version 14 or 15? This could be another issue. I've never tried to register the provider for VS2017.
Another thing is that you need to install the provider in your project before trying to run the DDEX provider. Usually I use the one on NuGet. I install the provider, compile the project, exit and enter in VS and then I see the DDEX provider in the list of providers.